# Change the character shown as tabs for a custom one

Tags: eclipse, ide, text-editor

In Eclipse, is it possible to change the characters that are shown when the option `Show whitespace characters` is enabled? If yes, how to do it?

[image]

Comment: No, the characters used are fixed in `org.eclipse.jface.text.WhitespaceCharacterPainter`

Comment: Then I will change the editor